# Can the MVC Controller method be mocked using the NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, mocking, nsubstitute

I need to test and mock a method found inside a controller. Is is possible to mock a method inside the controller, without implementing an interface using NSubstitute framework.

Here is my Controller page code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Syncfusion.Cluster.Manager
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: Home
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            int result = Sum(7, 7);
            return View();
        }

        public virtual int Sum(int a, int b)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Test code and the Sum always found to be '0' inside the controller while I debugged it. The Sum function inside the controller is not get overrides.

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;
using Manager;
using Base.Classes.Models.SecurityBase;
using NSubstitute;
using BaseProject;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace NSubstituteControllerSupport
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class UnitTest1
    {
        [Test]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            var controller = new HomeController();           
            //var actionMethod = Substitute.For<HomeController>();
            //actionMethod.Sum(Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>()).Returns(14);
            //var actual = controller.Index();

            var validation = Substitute.ForPartsOf<HomeController>();
            validation.When(x => x.Sum(a: Arg.Is(7), b: Arg.Is(7))).DoNotCallBase();
            validation.Sum(7, 7).Returns(14);
            var actuals = controller.Index();

        }
    }
}
```

Here is my testing code for the Class Library project I successfully mocked a method without implementing an interface.

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod2()
{
    #region variableDecleration
    var adHost = new ActiveDirectoryHost();
    adHost.AdPath = @"C:\User\Security\1.0.0.0";
    adHost.CnNames = "CN=USERS";
    adHost.DomainName = "USER.COM";
    adHost.DomainPath = "DC=USER,DC=COM";
    adHost.Fqn = "HOSTNAME.USER.COM.USER.COM";
    adHost.HostName = "hostname.user.com";
    adHost.OuPath = "OU=NewSecur";
    adHost.SuperGroupName = "usergroup_1";
    adHost.IpAddress = "xxx.xx.xx.x";
    var adUserName = "username";
    var adPassword = "password";
    #endregion variableDecleration

    var validation = Substitute.ForPartsOf<ValidationHandler>();
    validation.GetUserGroupList(userName: Arg.Is(adUserName ), recursive: Arg.Is(false), adHost: Arg.Is(adHost), adUsername: Arg.Is(adUserName), adPassword: Arg.Is(adPassword)).Returns("usergroup_1,usergroup_2");
    var isUserInGroup = validation.IsUserMemberOfGroup(adUsername, "usergroup_1", adHost, adUserName, adPassword);
    Assert.That(isUserInGroup, Is.EqualTo(true));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
// arrange
var controller = Substitute.For<HomeController>();
controller.Sum(7, 7).Returns(14);

// act
var actual = controller.Index();

// assert
...
```

Comment: I've just tried running this code and it worked perfectly. Notice that I do not create a new instance of `HomeController` manually using `new HomeController()` but rather ask NSubstitute to do it for me: `var controller = Substitute.For<HomeController>();`. Then assuming that your `Sum` method is indeed **virtual** and called with two parameters with values 7 and 7 it will return 14.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the flaw @Darin Dimitrov. It worked perfectly as expected

Comment: @DarinDimitrov I tried this but I gets null as the ActionResult , for other return types like int, I get proper value

Comment: @Jojo Me also getting same result as you mentioned. Any luck on that